# When an attribute depends on 2 classes, on which class should it be defined?

Tags: python, oop

Say I have 2 classes: `Water` and `Substance`. one or more `Substance`s can be dissolved in `Water`; a `Water` instance has a `substances` attribute containing a list of `Substance` instances. The diffusion constant of a `Substance` depends on the attributes of the `Water` it is dissolved in as well as some attributes of the `Substance` itself. Should I then make a `get_diffusion_constant` method on `Water` with an instance of `Substance` as its attribute, or should I add the method to `Substance` where `Water` is its argument? Or is there a different approach altogether?

Comment: You wrote "The diffusion constant of a Substance" meaning that the diffusion constant is an attribute of a substance. So the `get_diffusion_constant` should be a method of `Substance`

Comment: yeah, that is a valid argument. I have thought the same. But now when I have another method on `Water` that calculates some property of an substance that depends on the diffusion constant, I write: `self.substances[0].get_diffusion_constant(self)`.  Especially the self as an argument seems odd to me

Comment: Using `self` as an argument does not disturb me. It is just a reference to a `Water` instance as any other `Water` instance. The `self` argument name is just a convention that is, fortunately, used by everyone. But technically it has nothing special; you could define your methods with `this` (or `foo`, or anything else) as first parameter and use `this` (or `foo`, or anything else) as the current instance, it would work as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how this fits into the overall design of your system, but another option is a DiffusionConstant class, that takes a Water (and Substances?) as constructor args.  It can either do the calculation as part of the constructor, or as a method (perhaps named value).

Comment: @Tryph yes thanks for the reassurance it is OK coding. I'll keep it this way. You might make an answer out of it and I'll accept it.

Comment: @jrahhali this is also something that crossed my mind, But I find it a little heavy weight to make a whole class just for one function. Moreover, it complicates the rest of the design. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> The diffusion constant of a `Substance` depends on the attributes of the `Water`

This let think that the diffusion constant is a characteristic of the substance, so the `Substance` class should own the method that allows to compute it (with a parameter to provide a `Water` instance since it depends on it).

This works well for most simple case, if a real concepts owns a characteristic, its model (a class in this case) should own the related attribute or method.

Some design-patterns and/or more complex needs could justify to break this "rule" to introduce more astraction.

---

Additionally, to answer your comment: it is not a problem (IMO at least) to pass `self` to a function.
`self` is just a reference to the current instance and as nothing special except it is a widely respected convention for naming the current instance, and thus the first argument of (instance) methods.

To explain a bit more: an instance method must accept as first argument a reference to the related instance. By convention, this positional argument is named `self`, but you could decide to name it `this`, `instance` or whatever you want, it would be the same. Then you just would have to use the correct parameter name inside the method.

See the code below. It uses very bad names for the instance argument but it works as if `self` had been used:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(current_instance):
        current_instance.bar = 'baz'

    def __str__(this_name_is_ridiculous):
        return this_name_is_ridiculous.bar


print(Foo())  # prints baz
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `Water` inherits some stuff from `Substance`. So then you could have a `diffusion_constant` in each `Substance`and also a `diffuse` function with takes one or more `Substance`s

EDIT:

```
class Water:
     def diffuse(self, *args):
         #check if args is greater 0 or None and then iterate and apply diffusion_constants

class Substance:
      diffusion_constant = 0 #base constant

class Sirup(Substance):
      diffusion_constant = 3

#somewhere later then
corn_sirup = Sirup()
sugary_sirup = Sirup()
water = Water()
water.diffuse(corn_sirup, sugary_sirup)
```

EDIT:
Due to the comment I changed the code. Python has duck-typing, so as long your Substances have a `diffusion_constant` attribute, it is possible to access it, no matter what it is. This should then do it

Comment: Sorry, Water does not inherit from Substance. I can see the confusion, as Water is in some sense a Substance. But Substances in my case refer to Substances dissolved in Water